# Curved Monitor and Xbox One Setup

Tags: pc, xbox-one, monitor

### Setup

- [Alienware 34inch curved monitor (AW3418DW)](https://www.cnet.com/products/alienware-aw3418dw-monitor/specs/)
- first gen Xbox One.

### Problem

When I try to play Xbox on my monitor it displays in what seems to be full-screen mode, meaning there are black sidebars on the left and right sides.

#### Question

Is there a way to resolve this? I have seen videos of people be able to fix this with the Xbox one s and x but I haven't seen one for the first-gen Xbox.

Comment: A unrelated tip: You can try to re purpose the letterbox by using clamps or something to type tips and trick cheats on paper to hang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. [According to the Xbox support site](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/hardware-network/display-sound/tv-resolutions), the Xbox One only supports 16:9 resolutions such as 2560x1440. 21:9 resolutions such as 3440x1440 are not supported.

Comment: Thank you!! Beats chasing my tail trying to figure out how to make it work